# LibGdx don't draw properly a circle in float space

Tags: android, math, libgdx

My camera is set to a normalized space (1 unit in height and 1.5 unit in width). But it seems the circle algorithm of the ShapeRenderer works only in integer space. Is there a workaround ?

```
public void create() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 1.5f, 1f);
    shapes = new ShapeRenderer();
}

public void drawScene() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    shapes.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapes.begin(ShapeType.Circle);
    shapes.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    shapes.circle(0.75f, 0.5f,0.5f);
    shapes.end();
}
```

[image: It should be a circle]

Comment: You could try setting the segment count manually by calling ``ShapeRenderer.circle(float x, float y, float r, int segmentCount)``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShapeRenderer` uses [6 times the cube root of the radius](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.java#L474) to estimate how many segments it needs to draw a circle.

In your case that you end up with 4 segments (6 * 0.793 is roughly 4.76).  Which is what you see.

`ShapeRenderer` assumes units are screen pixels according to [the documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html), so these are reasonable estimates.